# Saving Parse Objects works only with a workaround

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am running into the following problem with saving objects to Parse. 
For some reason, when saving objects in the first code snippet, Parse hangs. The app doesn't crash, it just loads forever.

On the other hand, if we save things in the second manner, it works. What is crazy is that it is the same objects.

```
PFObject *huddle = request[SHRequestHuddleKey];
[huddle fetch];
        
Student *student1 = request[SHRequestStudent1Key];
[student1 fetch];
        
[student1 addObject:huddle forKey:SHStudentHuddlesKey];
[huddle addObject:student1 forKey:SHHuddleMembersKey];
        
[huddle saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Complete save huddle");
        }];
[student1 saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"complete save student");
        }]
```

---

```
PFObject *huddle = request[SHRequestHuddleKey];
[huddle fetchIfNeeded];

PFObject *student1 = request[SHRequestStudent1Key];
[student1 fetchIfNeeded];



NSString* s1ID = [student1 objectId];
PFQuery *query = [Student query];
PFObject* student = [query getObjectWithId:s1ID];
[huddle addObject:student forKey:SHHuddleMembersKey];

[huddle save];

NSString* huddleID = [huddle objectId];
PFQuery *huddleQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Huddles"];
PFObject* huddle2 = [huddleQuery getObjectWithId:huddleID];
[student addObject:huddle2 forKey:SHStudentHuddlesKey];
[student save];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're assigning student1 to a key on huddle, you only need to save huddle.  It will traverse all the related objects and save student1 too.  You can also use saveAll and pass in an NSArray of Parse Objects to save.

Since they're asynchronous, the way you had it at first could cause some real conflicts.  Both saves start and try saving both objects.

Are huddle and student1 objects that have already been saved?  At least one has to be saved if you're pointing both at each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot!.For some reason using [PFObject saveAll:[@huddle,student1]]; solved it but the other way (saving only huddle) failed. We think it might have something to do with the fact that they are array relations, not PFrelations.

Comment: Possibly..  Okay, if you can, hit the checkmark to mark this as the accepted answer.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding:

```
if(error){
   NSLog(@"Whatever");
}else{
   NSLog(@"Complete save huddle"); //You have 2 NSLogs here in your code BTW
}
```

between:

```
[huddle saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        //Add code above here
    }];
```

Just to see if you are getting an error?. I mean, sorry if this sounds ridiculous but I'm a beginner too just trying to help!

Comment: Thanks man, we also tried that and it doesnt print out anything. I dont think it even gets to that completion block